# Editing imageres.dll to customize system icons

Tags: windows-8.1, dll, desktop-customization

I wish to edit the imageres.dll file to change the shield overlay image that appears over elevated shortcuts.

I have found that when I edit the imageres.dll file, Windows immediately reverts it back to the original.  Is there a Windows tool that is doing this....some sort of file protection? Can it be turned off?

I want to edit imageres.dll and have it stay edited. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can, with "Resource Hacker". It's actually pretty easy to download, edit etc... Hope i helped!

Comment: (1) Please provide download information (e.g., a link to the site).  (2) Please describe how Resource Hacker answers the question.  (3) What is the mechanism that causes the `imageres.dll` to revert whenever the user edits it?  How does Resource Hacker overcome this protection?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.